# Get defaut collection image by Flickr API

Tags: flickr

I can get collections by method [flickr.collections.getTree](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.collections.getTree.html). Each collection have large and small url image. If collection have mosaic image, then url is full url like https:\farm2.staticflickr.com\xxxx/cols/yyy_zzz_l.jpg.

Otherwise url contain some default url: \images\collection_default_l.gif.

But what's the full default url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. Solution is simple, should add only flickr.com:

https://www.flickr.com/images/collection_default_l.gif